# Mongoose Querying Sub-Document Properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to expose this functionality through a WEB API. The way it is set up in this code is that someone does a GET on URL providing a querystring along with it in the form of:

`?field=value&anotherfield.subproperty=value`

But I can't seem to get querying based on sub-document properties to work. Below you will find my barebones code, record I'm trying to receive and both of my test cases.

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config');
var User = require('../models/user');
var functions = require('../functions');

router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {
    //Check Permissions associated with UID *TODO
    var parameters = req.query;
    console.log(parameters);
    User.find(parameters, function(err, users) {
        if (err)
        {
            json = functions.generateOperationOutcome("exception","error",err,"exception");
            res.status(500);
            res.json(json);
        }
        else
        {
            //Check for blank result
            if (users.length === 0)
            {
                json = functions.generateOperationOutcome("not-found","warning","Non-Existent Resource","warning");
                res.status(404);
                res.json(json);
            }
            else {
                res.status(200);
                res.json(users);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Record:

```
{
    "_id": "5871d2e814946a941d8611fb",
    "resourceType": "testResource",
    "link": [],
    "communication": [],
    "animal": {
      "genderStatus": {
        "coding": []
      },
      "breed": {
        "coding": []
      },
      "species": {
        "coding": []
      }
    },
    "contact": [],
    "photo": [],
    "maritalStatus": {
      "coding": []
    },
    "address": [],
    "gender": "unknown",
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "2019196553",
        "use": "home"
      }
    ],
    "name": {
      "suffix": [],
      "prefix": [],
      "given": [],
      "family": []
    },
    "identifier": [
      {
        "use": "official",
        "type": {
          "coding": {
            "system": "kylec laptop",
            "version": "0.01",
            "code": "UDI",
            "display": "Universal Device Identifier",
            "userSelected": false
          },
          "text": "test"
        },
        "system": "test system",
        "value": "test value",
        "assigner": {
          "reference": "test assigner reference"
        },
        "period": {
          "start": "1992-12-31T09:59:59+00:00"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Successful Query:

```
GET http://{{LOCAL}}/api/user?resourceType=testResource
```

Returns this one model from MongoDB.

Unsuccessful Query (no documents matching query found):

```
GET http://{{LOCAL}}/api/user?telecom.system=phone
```

Returns no models back and results in a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly using dot-notation, as the property you're seeking is within an array:

```
"telecom": [
  {
    "system": "phone",
    "value": "2019196553",
    "use": "home"
  }
]
```

Querying array content typically would require you to do a join against the array (for DocumentDB queries), and not a simple `find()`.

If you wanted the ability to use dot-notation here, you'd need to create a subdocument, like:

```
"telecom": {
    "system": "phone",
    "value": "2019196553",
    "use": "home"
  }
```

At this point, you'd be able to address properties such as `telecom.system`, `telecom.value`, and `telecom.use.`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate more on how we could utilize the queries against an array like we have? We're currently utilizing DocumentDB with MongoDB support so we're hoping there is mongoose/MongoDB way to accomplish this.

Comment: In pure MongoDB, you do this like [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index)